# scikit learn decision tree model evaluation

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Here are the related code and document, wondering for the default `cross_val_score` without explicitly specify `score`, the output array means precision, AUC or some other metrics?

Using Python 2.7 with miniconda interpreter.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>>> clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10)
...                             
...
array([ 1.     ,  0.93...,  0.86...,  0.93...,  0.93...,
        0.93...,  0.93...,  1.     ,  0.93...,  1.      ])
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation):

> By default, the score computed at each CV iteration is the score
>   method of the estimator. It is possible to change this by using the
>   scoring parameter:

From the DecisionTreeClassifier [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.score):

> Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels. In
>   multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a
>   harsh metric since you require for each sample that each label set be
>   correctly predicted.

Don't be confused by "mean accuracy," it's just the regular way one computes accuracy. Follow the links to the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/base.py#L285):

```
    from .metrics import accuracy_score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Now the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L171) for `metrics.accuracy_score`

```
def accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None):
    ...
    # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
        differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)
        score = differing_labels == 0
    else:
        score = y_true == y_pred

    return _weighted_sum(score, sample_weight, normalize)
```

And if you [still aren't convinced:](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L103)

```
def _weighted_sum(sample_score, sample_weight, normalize=False):
    if normalize:
        return np.average(sample_score, weights=sample_weight)
    elif sample_weight is not None:
        return np.dot(sample_score, sample_weight)
    else:
        return sample_score.sum()
```

Note: for `accuracy_score` normalize parameter defaults to `True`, thus it simply returns `np.average` of the boolean numpy arrays, thus it's simply the average number of correct predictions.

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga, if it is a two class classification problem, each prediction is either correct or wrong. Confused what means mean accuracy?

Comment: Thanks juanpa for the patience to answer, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a scoring argument isn't given, `cross_val_score` will default to using the `.score` method of the estimator you're using. For `DecisionTreeClassifier`, it's mean accuracy (as shown in the docstring below):

```
In [11]: DecisionTreeClassifier.score?
Signature: DecisionTreeClassifier.score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)
Docstring:
Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy
which is a harsh metric since you require for each sample that
each label set be correctly predicted.

Parameters
----------
X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features)
    Test samples.

y : array-like, shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
    True labels for X.

sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples], optional
    Sample weights.

Returns
-------
score : float
    Mean accuracy of self.predict(X) wrt. y.
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, if it is a two class classification problem, each prediction is either correct or wrong. Confused what means mean accuracy?

Comment: It's just the percentage of correct classifications if it's a two-class classification problem, assuming you're predicting 0/1. If you're predicting probabilities, it will be the average of (1-prediction error) for each prediction.